# SQL Query with variables

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Im trying to insert values into a mysql database:

```
database->queryDatabase("INSERT INTO recordings (title, recording, kit, date) VALUES ('"+recordingTitle+"', '"+ recordingArray +"', '"+kitID+"', '"+recordingDateTime+"')");
```

database->queryDatabase just sends it to my database connection.

The problem I am having is that:

```
error: no match for 'operator+' in 'operator+(const QString&, const char*)(((const char*)"\', \'")) + ((Studio*)this)->Studio::recordingDateTime
```

Each var is of type:

```
QString recordingTitle;
std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> > recordingArray;
int kitID;
QDateTime recordingDateTime;
```

How can I add each one to the database? The vector and QDateTime types do not like the + in the query string.

Tahnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no implicit conversion of `QDateTime` to `QString`. You'll need to explicitly convert it:

```
database->queryDatabase("INSERT INTO recordings (title, recording, kit, date)"
    " VALUES ('" + recordingTitle + "', '" + recordingArray +"', '" + kitID + 
        "', '" + recordingDateTime.toString() + "')");
```

You might have to provide a format specifier to get it into a format MySQL likes.

Answer (score 1):

Please also remember that concatenating for SQL queries is not a good idea, unless you know exactly what you are doing, since it enables [SQL-Injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection) attacks. You should use the [bindValue method](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/sql-sqlstatements.html#inserting-updating-and-deleting-records). This also has the side effect that you query will become faster and also most likely solve the original problem.